# how to get the value of another fragment that its not the current in an activity

Tags: android

i got a problem while working with fragments, in the first fragment i got a textview, ie:

```
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/LeyOrdenanza"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dpde10"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Ley / Ordenanza"
            android:textColor="@color/cafeoscuro"
            android:textColorHint="@color/cafeclaro"
            android:textSize="@dimen/legra25" />
```

the user puts a value, then i change of fragmet, in the new fragment i got a button that calls a function in the class that contains the fragments like this :

```
    EditText LeyOrdenanzav  =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LeyOrdenanza);
    LeyOrdenanza = LeyOrdenanzav.getText().toString();
```

but i get null, when i put the button with the function on the same fragment, everything works like a charm, but i need to change that button to the second fragment, thats when it stops working, any suggestions?...
[image: trying to explian the problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi i hope i got your question right,
in order to send data between fragments you need to create an interface communicator as follows, I'll suggest to make a new class so not to confuse yourself.

```
public interface Communicator {
 public void getData(String data);
}
```

Have your MainActivity Implement Communicator as follows.

`public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements Communicator`

after implementing the communicator add the umimplemented method which is getData in the form String in your Case.

this method will work as a hub between the two fragments.

Create an Instance of the Communicator in the fragment where you get the String from the TextView

```
Communicator communicator = (Communicator) getActivity();
```

Now Pass the String Like this `communicator.getData(StringtToPass);`

Initialize an instance of the Fragment in the method using Fragment Manger

`FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();                         fragmentTwo fragmentTwo = (fragmentTwo) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentTwo);`

On the Other fragment create a method similar to this

```
public void setData(String string) {
 textView.setText(stringPassed);
```

}

After you initialize the Fragment in the MainActivity you can pass the data this way.

```
fragmentTwo.setData(StringToPass);
```

Hope this will help a little.

Comment: it does not help "a little", it helps a lot, ill try to implement it and let you know how it goes, thx :)

Comment: god, love you dude, worked :), it was a silly question but got me a lot of time, thx....

Comment: Glad it helped, i absolutely Understand, i was pulling my hair when learning fragments.